# Implement methods to make program produce correct output (normally print true)

Tags: python

Why the program is printing false? I dont see the word "false" in the code. How to make it write true?
I am a beginner and doing a lot of exercises to practice python. Hope someone can help me!

[image: Codes]

[image: Results]

Comment: share code as text, not as image

Comment: The code is printing the result of a comparison (for example, `print(sum_ti(5)==15)`.  The result of a comparison is a boolean: True or False.  Because you haven't written the code yet, they all return False.  To make it print `True`, you have to write the `sum_to` and `factorial` and `digit_sum` functions.

Comment: Your first method returns `0` so the test in the prints don"t work, but that's normal, you need to implement the methods

Comment: i have flagged this question as it shows little effort and does not meet the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the functions called by `methods_program`. Since they all don't return anything or return `0`, the return value is not correct, which causes the comparison to be False. What you want to do is write code that makes your functions do what you want. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing site; this looks like an exercise for you to learn. If you need hints, ask. Don't give us a general requirement and have us write away.